# In AngularFire how do we get storage reference like in normal javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire, firebase-storage

By using normal Javascript I can use firebase storage like the code below

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCJ3RdrcdO_Zph5DKPN-RLmJsR5fBD7S5w",
    authDomain: "myapp-90faa.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://myapp-90faa.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "myapp-90faa.appspot.com",
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

// file from some event e
var file = e.target.files[0];
var storage = firebase.storage().ref('images/'+file.name);
var task = storage.put(file);
```

But how to achive the storage object in Angular fire? here I just can refer to a database:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['firebase']);
var myProducts = new Firebase('https://myapp-90faa.firebaseio.com/products');

myApp.controller('ProductsCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', function($scope,$firebaseArray) {
```

Comment: Firebase Storage is not (yet) wrapped in AngularFire 2.x. See this [Github issue tracking its progress](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/785).

Answer (score 0):

For AngularJS it has been possible since version 2.3 of [Angularfire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#firebasestorage):

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", "$firebaseStorage",
    function($scope, $firebaseStorage) {
        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("images/dog");
        $scope.storage = $firebaseStorage(storageRef);
    }
]);
```

For Angular beyond version 1.x, [AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) also has an API for firebase storage:

```
constructor(private fb: FirebaseApp) {
    const storageRef = fb.storage().ref("images/dog")
}
```